# Update a parser to admit parentheses within quoted strings

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I need to update a parser to admit these new features, but I am not able to manage all them at a time:

- The commands must admit an indeterminate number of parameters (> 0).
- Parameters might be numbers, unquoted strings or quoted strings.
- Parameters are separate by commas.
- Within quoted strings, it shall be permitted to use opening/closing parenthesis.

(It easier to understand these requirements looking at source code example)

My current code, including checks, is as follows:

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/5d6o53n9h

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace script
{
    struct Command
    {
        enum Type { NONE, WRITE_LOG, INSERT_LABEL, START_PROCESS, END_PROCESS, COMMENT, FAIL };

        Type type{ Type::NONE };
        std::vector<std::string> args;
    };

    using Commands = std::vector<Command>;
}//namespace script

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(script::Command, type, args)

namespace script
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It>
    class Parser : public qi::grammar<It, Commands()>
    {
    private:
        qi::symbols<char, Command::Type> type;
        qi::rule<It, Command(), qi::blank_type> none, command, comment, fail;//By its very nature "fail" must be the last one to be checked
        qi::rule<It, Commands()> start;

    public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start)
        {
            using namespace qi;//NOTE: "as_string" is neccessary in all args due to std::vector<std::string>
            auto empty_args = copy(attr(std::vector<std::string>{}));

            type.add
                ("WriteLog", Command::WRITE_LOG)
                ("InsertLabel", Command::INSERT_LABEL)
                ("StartProcess", Command::START_PROCESS)
                ("EndProcess", Command::END_PROCESS);

            none = omit[*blank] >> &(eol | eoi)
                >> attr(Command::NONE)
                >> empty_args;//ignore args

            command = type >> '('
                >> as_string[lexeme[+~char_("(),\r\n")]] % ',' >> ')';

            comment = lit("//")
                >> attr(Command::COMMENT)
                >> as_string[lexeme[*~char_("\r\n")]];

            fail = omit[*~char_("\r\n")]
                >> attr(Command::FAIL)
                >> empty_args;//ignore args

            start = skip(blank)[(none | command | comment | fail) % eol] >> eoi;
        }
    };

    Commands parse(std::istream& in)
    {
        using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
        static const Parser<It> parser;

        Commands commands;

        It first(in >> std::noskipws), last;//No white space skipping
        if (!qi::parse(first, last, parser, commands))
            throw std::runtime_error("command parse error");

        return commands;
    }
}//namespace script

std::stringstream ss{
R"(// just a comment

WriteLog("this is a log")
WriteLog("this is also (in another way) a log")
WriteLog("but this is just a fail)

StartProcess(17, "program.exe", True)
StartProcess(17, "this_is_a_fail.exe, True)
)"};

int main()
{
    using namespace script;

    try
    {
        auto commands = script::parse(ss);

        std::array args{ 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, 0, 3, -1, 0 };//Fails may have any number of arguments. It doesn't care. Sets as -1 by convenience flag
        std::array types{ Command::COMMENT, Command::NONE, Command::WRITE_LOG, Command::WRITE_LOG, Command::FAIL, Command::NONE, Command::START_PROCESS, Command::FAIL, Command::NONE };
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << "size correct? " << (commands.size() == 9) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "types correct? " << std::equal(commands.begin(), commands.end(), types.begin(), types.end(), [](auto& cmd, auto& type) { return cmd.type == type; }) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "arguments correct? " << std::equal(commands.begin(), commands.end(), args.begin(), args.end(), [](auto& cmd, auto arg) { return cmd.args.size() == arg || arg == -1; }) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to allow parentheses within quoted strings. But you don't even support quoted strings!

So the problem is your argument rule. Which doesn't even exist. It whould be roughly this part:

```
argument = +~char_("(),\r\n");
command = type >> '(' >> argument % ',' >> ')';
```

Where `argument` might be declared as

```
qi::rule<It, Argument()> argument;
```

In fact, rewriting the tests in an organized fashion, here's what we get right now:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Mv74MTP58)**

```
static const Commands expected{
    {Command::COMMENT, {"just a comment"}},
    {Command::NONE, {}},
    {Command::WRITE_LOG, {"this is a log"}},
    {Command::WRITE_LOG, {"this is also (in another way) a log"}},
    {Command::FAIL, {}},
    {Command::NONE, {}},
    {Command::START_PROCESS, {"17", "program.exe", "True"}},
    {Command::FAIL, {}},
    {Command::NONE, {}},
};

try {
    auto parsed = script::parse(ss);
    fmt::print("Parsed all correct? {} -- {} parsed (vs. {} expected)\n",
               (parsed == expected), parsed.size(), expected.size());

    for (auto i = 0u; i < std::min(expected.size(), parsed.size()); ++i) {
        if (expected[i] != parsed[i]) {
            fmt::print("index #{} expected {}\n"
                       "          actual:  {}\n",
                       i, expected[i], parsed[i]);
        } else {
            fmt::print("index #{} CORRECT ({})\n", i, parsed[i]);
        }
    }
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    fmt::print("Exception: {}\n", e.what());
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed all correct? false -- 9 parsed (vs. 9 expected)
index #0 CORRECT (Command(COMMENT, ["just a comment"]))
index #1 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #2 expected Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is a log"])
          actual:  Command(WRITE_LOG, ["\"this is a log\""])
index #3 expected Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is also (in another way) a log"])
          actual:  Command(FAIL, [])
index #4 expected Command(FAIL, [])
          actual:  Command(WRITE_LOG, ["\"but this is just a fail"])
index #5 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #6 expected Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "program.exe", "True"])
          actual:  Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "\"program.exe\"", "True"])
index #7 expected Command(FAIL, [])
          actual:  Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "\"this_is_a_fail.exe", "True"])
index #8 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
```

As you can see, it fails quoted strings too, in my expectation. That's because the quoting is a language construct. In the AST (parsed results) you donot care about how exactly it was written in code. E.g.  `"hello\ world\041"` might be equivalent too `"hello world!"` so both should result in the argument value `hello world!`.

So, let's do as we say:

```
argument = quoted_string | number | boolean | raw_string;
```

We can add a few rules:

```
// notice these are lexemes (no internal skipping):
qi::rule<It, Argument()> argument, quoted_string, number, boolean, raw_string;
```

And define them:

```
quoted_string = '"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"';
number        = raw[double_];
boolean       = raw[bool_];
raw_string    = +~char_("(),\r\n");
argument      = quoted_string | number | boolean | raw_string;
```

> (If you want to allow escaped quotes, something like this:
>
> ```
>  quoted_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
> ```

Now, I'd say you probably want `Argument` to be something like `variant<double, std::string, bool>`, instead of just `std::string`.

With only this change, all the problems have ***practically*** vanished: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5vdojrv45)**:

```
Parsed all correct? false -- 9 parsed (vs. 9 expected)
index #0 CORRECT (Command(COMMENT, ["just a comment"]))
index #1 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #2 CORRECT (Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is a log"]))
index #3 CORRECT (Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is also (in another way) a log"]))
index #4 CORRECT (Command(FAIL, []))
index #5 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #6 CORRECT (Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "program.exe", "True"]))
index #7 expected Command(FAIL, [])
          actual:  Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "this_is_a_fail.exe, True)\n\"this_is_a_fail.exe", "True"])
index #8 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
```

Now, index #7 *looks* very funky, but it's actually a well-known phenomenon in Spirit¹. [Enabling BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG](https://godbolt.org/z/T63Tz5MT9) demonstrates it:

```xml
  <argument>
    <try>"this_is_a_fail.exe,</try>
    <quoted_string>
      <try>"this_is_a_fail.exe,</try>
      <fail/>
    </quoted_string>
    <number>
      <try>"this_is_a_fail.exe,</try>
      <fail/>
    </number>
    <boolean>
      <try>"this_is_a_fail.exe,</try>
      <fail/>
    </boolean>
    <raw_string>
      <try>"this_is_a_fail.exe,</try>
      <success>, True)</success>
      <attributes>[[t, h, i, s, _, i, s, _, a, _, f, a, i, l, ., e, x, e, ,,  , T, r, u, e, ), ", t, h, i, s, _, i, s, _, a, _, f, a, i, l, ., e, x, e]]</attributes>
    </raw_string>
    <success>, True)</success>
    <attributes>[[t, h, i, s, _, i, s, _, a, _, f, a, i, l, ., e, x, e, ,,  , T, r, u, e, ), ", t, h, i, s, _, i, s, _, a, _, f, a, i, l, ., e, x, e]]</attributes>
  </argument>
```

So, the string gets accepted as a raw string, even though it started with `"`. That's easily fixed, but we don't even need to. We could just apply `qi::hold` to avoid the duplication:

```
argument = qi::hold[quoted_string] | number | boolean | raw_string;
```

Result:

```
actual:  Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "\"this_is_a_fail.exe", "True"])
```

However, if you expect it to fail, fix that other problem:

```
raw_string    = +~char_("\"(),\r\n"); // note the \"
```

> Note: In the off-chance you really only require it to *not start* with
> a quote:
>
> ```
> raw_string    = !lit('"') >> +~char_("(),\r\n");
> ```
>
> I guess by now you see the problem with a "loose rule" like that, so I
> don't recommend it.
>
> You could express the requirement another way though, saying "if an
> argument starts with `'"'` then is **MUST** be a `quoted_string`. Use
> an expectation point there:
>
> ```
> quoted_string = '"' > *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) > '"';
> ```
>
> This has the effect that failure to parse a complete `quoted_string`
> [will throw an `expectation_failed` exception](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vPJbbInIb2nsCccx).

### Summary / Listing

This is what we end up with:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TK7PoYW8r)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

namespace script {
    using Argument = std::string;
    using Arguments = std::vector<Argument>;

    struct Command {
        enum Type {
            NONE,
            WRITE_LOG,
            INSERT_LABEL,
            START_PROCESS,
            END_PROCESS,
            COMMENT,
            FAIL
        };

        Type      type{Type::NONE};
        Arguments args;

        auto operator<=>(Command const&) const = default;
    };

    using Commands = std::vector<Command>;
} // namespace script

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(script::Command, type, args)

namespace script {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It> class Parser : public qi::grammar<It, Commands()> {
    public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi; // NOTE: "as_string" is neccessary in all args
            auto empty_args = copy(attr(Arguments{}));

            type.add //
                ("WriteLog",     Command::WRITE_LOG)     //
                ("InsertLabel",  Command::INSERT_LABEL)  //
                ("StartProcess", Command::START_PROCESS) //
                ("EndProcess",   Command::END_PROCESS);  //

            none = omit[*blank] >> &(eol | eoi) //
                >> attr(Command{Command::NONE, {}});

            quoted_string = '"' >> *('\\' >> char_ | ~char_('"')) >> '"';
            number        = raw[double_];
            boolean       = raw[bool_];
            raw_string    = +~char_("\"(),\r\n");
            argument = qi::hold[quoted_string] | number | boolean | raw_string;

            command = type >> '(' >> argument % ',' >> ')';

            comment = "//"                             //
                >> attr(Command::COMMENT)              //
                >> as_string[lexeme[*~char_("\r\n")]]; //

            fail = omit[*~char_("\r\n")] >> attr(Command{Command::FAIL, {}});

            line  = none | command | comment | fail; // keep fail last
            start = skip(blank)[line % eol] >> eoi;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(line)(fail)(comment)(command)(
                argument)(none)(quoted_string)(raw_string)(boolean)(number))
        }

    private:
        qi::symbols<char, Command::Type>         type;
        qi::rule<It, Command(), qi::blank_type>  line, none, command, comment, fail;
        // notice these are lexemes (no internal skipping):
        qi::rule<It, Argument()> argument, quoted_string, number, boolean, raw_string;
        qi::rule<It, Commands()> start;
    };

    Commands parse(std::istream& in)
    {
        using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
        static const Parser<It> parser;

        Commands commands;

        return qi::parse(It{in >> std::noskipws}, {}, parser, commands)
            ? commands
            : throw std::runtime_error("command parse error");
    }

    struct Formatter {
        static constexpr auto name(script::Command::Type type) {
            return std::array{"NONE",          "WRITE_LOG",   "INSERT_LABEL",
                            "START_PROCESS", "END_PROCESS", "COMMENT",
                            "FAIL"}
                .at(static_cast<int>(type));
        }

        auto parse(auto& ctx) const { return ctx.begin(); }
        auto format(script::Command const& cmd, auto& ctx) const {
            return format_to(ctx.out(), "Command({}, {})", name(cmd.type), cmd.args);
        }
    };
} // namespace script

template <> struct fmt::formatter<script::Command> : script::Formatter {};

std::stringstream ss{
    R"(// just a comment

    WriteLog("this is a log")
    WriteLog("this is also (in another way) a log")
    WriteLog("but this is just a fail)

    StartProcess(17, "program.exe", True)
    StartProcess(17, "this_is_a_fail.exe, True)
    )"};

int main() {
    using namespace script;
    static const Commands expected{
        {Command::COMMENT, {"just a comment"}},
        {Command::NONE, {}},
        {Command::WRITE_LOG, {"this is a log"}},
        {Command::WRITE_LOG, {"this is also (in another way) a log"}},
        {Command::FAIL, {}},
        {Command::NONE, {}},
        {Command::START_PROCESS, {"17", "program.exe", "True"}},
        {Command::FAIL, {}},
        {Command::NONE, {}},
    };

    try {
        auto parsed = script::parse(ss);
        fmt::print("Parsed all correct? {} -- {} parsed (vs. {} expected)\n",
                (parsed == expected), parsed.size(), expected.size());

        for (auto i = 0u; i < std::min(expected.size(), parsed.size()); ++i) {
            if (expected[i] != parsed[i]) {
                fmt::print("index #{} expected {}\n"
                        "          actual:  {}\n",
                        i, expected[i], parsed[i]);
            } else {
                fmt::print("index #{} CORRECT ({})\n", i, parsed[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        fmt::print("Exception: {}\n", e.what());
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed all correct? true -- 9 parsed (vs. 9 expected)
index #0 CORRECT (Command(COMMENT, ["just a comment"]))
index #1 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #2 CORRECT (Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is a log"]))
index #3 CORRECT (Command(WRITE_LOG, ["this is also (in another way) a log"]))
index #4 CORRECT (Command(FAIL, []))
index #5 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
index #6 CORRECT (Command(START_PROCESS, ["17", "program.exe", "True"]))
index #7 CORRECT (Command(FAIL, []))
index #8 CORRECT (Command(NONE, []))
```

---

¹ see e.g. [boost::spirit alternative parsers return duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050263/boostspirit-alternative-parsers-return-duplicates/66053046#66053046) (which links to three more of the same kind)

Comment: This is what I had in mind with the `variant<>` argument type: https://godbolt.org/z/b5rfj4xaY (it takes too much time on Godbolt to compile, but it prints https://i.imgur.com/462cdKR.png)

Comment: Thank you, this is pure gold. I have learnt a lot of both ```boost::spirit``` and english speaking (yeap, I should have double check that "parenthesis" before typing). Also, your variant based solution is great, but I wonder why you use boost::variant instead of std::variant? Your code is using new c++20 string format, so it is greater than c++17 std::variant. Do you consider boost::variant better than standard for any reason?

Comment: It's just a little bit more idiomatic with Spirit, for historical reasons. Honestly, I'm temtped to reverse the question: Do you consider std:;variant better than boost::variant for any reason :) [std::variant c++20](https://godbolt.org/z/EMPvs9hhv). But I cheated, it was using libfmt, so [c++17](https://godbolt.org/z/bMocEGnnd), [c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/od94vvW8T) and with considerable heroics [c++11](https://godbolt.org/z/4afEeoKMc) can all use it.

Comment: C++03 is not actually supported by libfmt, but with considerably more heroics it can be done without: [c++03](https://godbolt.org/z/s1bn1dTTc) (it does compile faster though...)