# Parsing ipv4 address with Boost Spirit X3

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, ipv4, boost-spirit-x3

X3 newbie here. Two questions:

1. Why the result contains repeated "1,1,1"s, like so: `<attributes>[[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, 1, 1, ., 1, 1, 1], [8, 0]]</attributes>`, when I expect something like this `<attributes>[[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, ., 1], [8, 0]]</attributes>`
2. What would be not-so-awkward way to define a single char to be expanded to (treated like ?) a sequence in dec_octet rule. I've used `x3::repeat(1)[x3::digit]`, but this seems wrong and probably causes errors of first question. (`x3::repeat(1)[x3::digit]` is used because it seems I can'not just use x3::digit instead, because it would fail rule collapsing ?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>


namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast
{
    struct ip_port
    {
        std::string host;
        boost::optional<std::string> port;
    };

}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::ip_port, host, port)

namespace parser
{
    template <typename T> auto as = [](auto name, auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T> {name} = p; };
    
    const auto dec_octet = as<std::string>("dec_octet",
            (
              x3::char_('2') >> x3::char_('5') >> x3::char_('0', '5')
            | x3::char_('2') >> x3::char_('0', '4') >> x3::digit
            | x3::char_('1') >> x3::digit >> x3::digit          
            | x3::char_('1', '9') >> x3::digit
            | x3::repeat(1)[x3::digit] // awkward way to force sequence from single char, but can't use x3::digit
            )

    );

    const auto ipv4address = as<std::string>("ipv4address",
      dec_octet >> x3::char_('.') >> dec_octet >> x3::char_('.') >> dec_octet >> x3::char_('.') >> dec_octet
    );

    const auto ip = as<std::string>("host", ipv4address);
    const auto port = as<std::string>("port", +x3::digit);
    const auto ip_port = as<ast::ip_port>("ip_port",  ip >> -((':') >> port));
}


template <typename T, typename Parser>
bool parse(const std::string& in, const Parser& p)
{
    T parsed;
    auto iter = in.begin();
    auto end_iter = in.end();
    bool res = x3::parse(iter, end_iter, p, parsed);
    
    return res && (iter == end_iter);
}


int main()
{
    std::cerr << std::boolalpha << parse<ast::ip_port>(std::string{"192.168.1.1:80"}, parser::ip_port) << '\n';
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Debug output:

```
<ip_port>
  <try>192.168.1.1:80</try>
  <host>
    <try>192.168.1.1:80</try>
    <ipv4address>
      <try>192.168.1.1:80</try>
      <dec_octet>
        <try>192.168.1.1:80</try>
        <success>.168.1.1:80</success>
        <attributes>[1, 9, 2]</attributes>
      </dec_octet>
      <dec_octet>
        <try>168.1.1:80</try>
        <success>.1.1:80</success>
        <attributes>[1, 6, 8]</attributes>
      </dec_octet>
      <dec_octet>
        <try>1.1:80</try>
        <success>.1:80</success>
        <attributes>[1, 1, 1]</attributes>
      </dec_octet>
      <dec_octet>
        <try>1:80</try>
        <success>:80</success>
        <attributes>[1, 1, 1]</attributes>
      </dec_octet>
      <success>:80</success>
      <attributes>[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, 1, 1, ., 1, 1, 1]</attributes>
    </ipv4address>
    <success>:80</success>
    <attributes>[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, 1, 1, ., 1, 1, 1]</attributes>
  </host>
  <port>
    <try>80</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[8, 0]</attributes>
  </port>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, 1, 1, ., 1, 1, 1], [8, 0]]</attributes>
</ip_port>
true
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** 1. Why the result contains repeated "1,1,1"s, like so: [[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, 1, 1, ., 1, 1, 1], [8, 0]], when I expect something like this [[1, 9, 2, ., 1, 6, 8, ., 1, ., 1], [8, 0]]

It's been 7 days since [the last time people ran into this pitfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050263/boostspirit-alternative-parsers-return-duplicates/66053046#66053046):

> It's the age-old "container attributes aren't atomic" pitfall:
>
> - [boost::spirit::qi duplicate parsing on the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869978/boostspiritqi-duplicate-parsing-on-the-output/13875183#13875183)
> - [Understanding Boost.spirit's string parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959270/understanding-boost-spirits-string-parser/21960981#21960981)
> - [Parsing with Boost::Spirit (V2.4) into container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912674/parsing-with-boostspirit-v2-4-into-container/3915892)
>
> You can paper over it using `qi::hold`. Or you can revise your
> strategy.

Like in that case, I'd advise to use `raw` to get the underlying source sequence instead.

> **Q.**
> 2. [...] not so awkward [...]

The intermediate step would be

```
const auto dec_octet = x3::raw [ x3::uint_parser<uint8_t>{} ];
```

Boom. Use the fact that X3 is a highlevel parser generator. Don't do the nitty gritty, error prone work. In fact, you could simply

```
const x3::uint_parser<std::uint8_t> dec_octet{};
```

Which defers the "stringification" to the point where it's needed:

```
const x3::uint_parser<std::uint8_t> dec_octet{};
const x3::uint_parser<std::uint16_t> port{};

const auto ipv4address = x3::raw [
      dec_octet >> '.' >> dec_octet >> '.' >> dec_octet >> '.' >> dec_octet ];

const auto ip_port = as<ast::ip_port>("ip_port", ipv4address >> -(':' >> port));
```

### After Liposuction

Note the use of `uint16_t` for the port, `x3::eoi` to expect full parse, removal of explicit rule/conversions:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d8a74b61e0c42f9)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    struct ip_port {
        std::string host;
        boost::optional<uint16_t> port;
    };
    using boost::fusion::operator<<;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::ip_port, host, port)

namespace parser {
    const x3::uint_parser<uint8_t> dec_octet {};
    const x3::uint_parser<uint16_t> port {};

    const auto ipv4address = x3::raw[dec_octet >> '.' >> dec_octet >> '.'
        >> dec_octet >> '.' >> dec_octet];

    const auto ip_port = ipv4address >> -(':' >> port) >> x3::eoi;
}

template <typename Parser, typename Attr>
static inline bool parse(std::string_view in, Parser const& p, Attr& result)
{
    return x3::parse(in.begin(), in.end(), p, result);
}

auto parse_ipport(std::string_view in)
{
    ast::ip_port result;
    if (!parse(in, parser::ip_port, result))
        throw std::invalid_argument("ipv4address");

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto input : { "192.168.1.1:80", "1.1.1.1", ":" }) {
        std::cerr << parse_ipport(input) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
(192.168.1.1  80)
(1.1.1.1 --)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  ipv4address
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Simplifying the code some more [by removing the `optional`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30f9ba76895c0101):

```
(192.168.1.1 80)
(1.1.1.1 0)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  ipv4address
```

### Out-Of-The-Box

Note: your grammar doesn't match all RFC compliant ip v4 addresses. E.g.

- `127.1` is valid for `127.0.0.1`.
- so is `0177.1` or `0x7f.1`

Either fix it for real or don't re-invent the wheel, using `boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string` or even `boost::asio::ip::address::from_string` and getting IPv6 support for free.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this superuseful answer ! I've probably somehow missed x3::uint_parser in official documentation, but I still can not see it there. Is there any other place I can look for x3 reference doc ?

Comment: using  const x3::uint_parser<uint8_t> dec_octet {};  is not as strict as the OP tentative.
it successfully parse "01.1.2.3" which according to rfc3986 is not a valid ip.